# Indexing and syntax highlighting not working in Xcode when using a Makefile to build

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile, clang, lldb

I'm using Xcode for a C++ project that uses a Makefile to build. The problem is, that Xcode doesn't seem to index the source on the fly (or at all). I have no syntax highlighting, no live compile error warnings and I can't "Jump to definition", because I get a "Symbol Not Found" error.

Is it possible to get Xcode doing all these things when using Makefiles or will I have to add an additional C++ target?

Comment: Why are you using a Makefile?

Comment: Because it's a team project and not everyone is using Xcode.

Comment: You can use both; I have a project that both builds from the command line (using `make`) and from within Xcode (and I guess also from the command using `xcodebuild`, but I don't use that).

Comment: You can maintain the project in makefile and Xcode project simultaneously - although obviously changes need to be made to both over the life of the project.  I think Xcode uses the clang compiler to do its indexing so if it doesn't know how to build any of the files, you may not get that feature.  I'm not an expert in this area but that sounds right.

Comment: I'm doing that now. But it's quite annoying to manage both.

Comment: Have you looked into `cmake`? I know that it provides some nice tools for at least generating xcode projects.

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode to index your project you have to add another target, choose "Command line tools" for target type. Then add all `.c` and `.cpp` (and any other source file you want to be indexed) to the compile resources in build phases. You should get syntax highlighting after a few moments (might take longer depending on size of your project.

[image]

Compiler warnings/errors should appear depending on your project settings. If not you have to revisit your schema and target settings. I'll be posting a c project on my github shortly which does all these.

**UPDATE 1**

Sample C Project in Xcode https://github.com/CaziSoft/BLE-Keyboard

**UPDATE 2**
To my understanding you can't debug any C/C++ apps unless you can use `LLDB`. `GDB` is not supported anymore.